# How do I make a random folder load inside a div on load

Tags: html, css, random

Ok, first of all I'm sorry if my question appears unclear as I'm going to find it hard to explain. I don't know if you guys help with the coding at all but if you could set me off in the right direction that would be great.

**Overview**-
Basically similar to that of YouTube where on the side panel under "recommended >>" There is a single column with different rows. On each row there is a `<div>` element which contains a picture, title, who uploaded it and views. So these different parts so the title picture etc. are specific and link to that one video. I know the different videos that are recommended are based on numourous factors etc. But, anyway driving to the point here now-

**Q**- Is there a way of making the page load a random element or shall we say set for a video within a `<div>` tag?

I'll put up some code to demonstrate the basic layout:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="thumbnail">
<img src="thumbnail.png"
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div id="author">
<a> somebody </a>
</div>
</td>
```

... and so forth.
I have read up on how to make a random image come up upon load but is there a way of making a whole section or say a random style sheet come up on load? and each contain the different videos ( Just taking a stab in the dark here) or some sort of script?. Again I'm sorry if I'm sounded very vague or if I'm using the wrong terminology...

Comment: Is any of the data you want to randomly load in a database or is it just a random image or something you want to do. Also have you thought about what language you using?

Comment: sure there are ways. You could work with a database in the back, you could work with a predefined list of objects and load randomly one of them and so on. There are multiple possibilities. You must figure out what fits your needs at best.

Comment: Well to be honest i assumed it would be more practical through jquery or javascript. But, as you both brought up the idea of databases it probably is the most feasable method. However, what should i look into as far programming is concerned? well.. are there any specific parts as in like mysql,sql as this is a very niche area for me. Also would you recommend any starter websites?